# Virtual Print function not working properly for the derived class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I want the `Print()` function, declared virtual in the base `class ParticleType` , to print on screen, other than the correct values for `mass_` and `charge` the correct value for `width`. The function works as intended for the base class. Here is my code :

ParticleType.h

```
#ifndef PARTICLETYPE_H
#define PARTICLETYPE_H
#include <iostream>

class ParticleType {

public:

ParticleType(char name, double mass, int charge) ;

ParticleType() ;

char Getname() const  ;
double Getmass() const ;
int Getcharge() const  ;
virtual double Getwidth() const ;

virtual void Print() const  ;

private:
char const name_ ;
const double mass_ ;
const int charge_;
} ;
#endif
```

ParticleType.C

```
#include "ParticleType.h"

ParticleType::ParticleType(char name, double mass, int charge) :
name_{name} , mass_{mass} , charge_{charge} {};

ParticleType::ParticleType() :
name_{'v'} , mass_{0} , charge_{0} {} ;

char ParticleType::Getname() const {
 return name_ ;
} 

double ParticleType::Getmass() const {
    return mass_;
}

int ParticleType::Getcharge() const {
    return charge_ ;
}

double ParticleType::Getwidth() const {
    return 0;
}

void ParticleType::Print() const  {
    std::cout << "Name: " << Getname() << " Mass: " << Getmass() << " Charge: " << Getcharge()
    << '\n';
}
```

ResonanceType.h

```
#ifndef RESONANCETYPE_H
#define RESONANCETYPE_H
#include "ParticleType.h"

class ResonanceType : virtual public ParticleType {
 public :
 
ResonanceType(char name, double mass, int charge, double width) ;

ResonanceType() ;

double Getwidth() const ;

void Print() const ;

 private:

const double width_ ;

} ;

#endif
```

ResonanceType.C

```
#include "ResonanceType.h"

ResonanceType::ResonanceType(char name, double mass, int charge, double width) :
ParticleType(name,charge,mass), width_{width}  {}; 

ResonanceType::ResonanceType() : 
ParticleType() , width_{}  {};

double ResonanceType::Getwidth() const {
    return width_ ;
}

void ResonanceType::Print() const {
    ParticleType::Print();
    std::cout << "Width : " << Getwidth() << '\n' ;
}
```

and finally my main

```
#include "ResonanceType.h"
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<ParticleType> v ;
    ResonanceType r = ResonanceType('k',0.89166,0,0.050) ;
    ParticleType p = ParticleType('p',0.13957,1) ;
    v.push_back(r);
    v.push_back(p) ;
    v[0].Print() ;
    v[1].Print() ;
}
```

this is the output I get :

```
Name: k Mass: 0 Charge: 0
Name: p Mass: 0.13957 Charge: 1
```

Comment: @StephenNewell I don't think so, surely because I'm not understanding. I still initialize 'r' as a 'ResonanceType', does it get sliced when pushing it in the vector?

Comment: Since the vector stores only `ParticleType` objects, pushiing a `ResonanceType` object into it will slice the object and only store the base `ParticleType` of `r`.

Comment: Also see [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing).